# Как запретить повторное воспроизведение видео?

Tags: видео

Здравствуйте, уважаемые. На просторах интернета нашел скрипт (сам в этом мало что понимаю, только учусь), который запускает HTML5 видео автоматически при его попадании в видимую часть экрана посетителя при скроллинге. Вот этот код скрипта:

```
    var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video"), fraction = 0.8;

    function checkScroll() {
        for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
            var video = videos[i];
            var x = video.offsetLeft, y = video.offsetTop, w = video.offsetWidth, h = video.offsetHeight, r = x + w, //right
                b = y + h, //bottom
                visibleX, visibleY, visible;
                visibleX = Math.max(0, Math.min(w, window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - x, r - window.pageXOffset));
                visibleY = Math.max(0, Math.min(h, window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - y, b - window.pageYOffset));
                visible = visibleX * visibleY / (w * h);
                if (visible > fraction) {
                    video.play();
                }
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
    window.addEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false);
```

И сама html-разметка, как вариант:

```
<video id="video1" width="424">
    <source src="aw1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="aw1.WebM" type="video/webm">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

В работе можно посмотреть здесь http://ac.alche.in.ua/work/

Так вот, есть ли возможность запретить повторное использование скрипта? Или повторное воспроизведение видео. Чтобы при втором-третьем прокручивании страницы видео опять не воспроизводилось.
Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю убрать обработчики при запуске воспроизведения:

```
if (visible > fraction) {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
  window.removeEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false);
  video.play();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Данный вариант тоже работает на отлично)

Answer (score 0):

элементарно:  переменная(признак того, что видео уже воспроизводилось) = true

```
var priznak = false;

if (visible > fraction) {
   if (!priznak) {
       video.play();
       priznak = true;
   }
}
```

Код расписал подробно, чтоб было понятнее

Comment: Ты про булевский тип вообще слышал? Что за жуть со строками? И ещё скобку пропустил...

Comment: Стоп.. А что тут вообще else делает? Присваивание должно быть в той же ветви.

Comment: Спасибо. Работает хорошо.